# Rxjs: take(1) usage

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, rxjs

I have seen a tutorial on rxjs as like this.

My question is: 
1) What is the usage of `take(1)` here? I see a lot of explanation online but i don't really get it. Also, i don't see any benefit of using `take(1)` in this code. And the author do use `take(1)` on every return function in REST api related service.

2) The author did not unsubscribe after subscribe. Is it because the author use `take(1)` therefore manual unsubscribe is not needed?

3) What if i want to implement catch function. Should i implement it before take or after take.

```
getProfile() { // this is a call to REST API
    return this.service.getProfile()
            .map(res => res.json())
            .take(1)
    }
}

this.data.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
    this.userProfile = profile;
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> The author did not unsubscribe after subscribe. Is it because the
> author use take(1) therefore manual unsubscribe is not needed?

Yes, that is most likely why the author uses `take(1)` operator. You can read more about take operator [here](https://indepth.dev/reference/rxjs/operators/take). Its job is to pass one value to an observable and then unsubscribe from the source. But depending on the service it may not be required.

For example in Angular the `HttpClient` service completes the stream by itself after sending the final `HttpResponse` event value so you don't need to neither use `take` nor unsubscribe explicitly. [Here is the sources](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e2e8ba6ffa382319c4f8b8cc4bc43814e7c0f97c/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts#L207):

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpXhrBackend implements HttpBackend {
  ...
  handle(req: HttpRequest<any>): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    ...
    // Everything happens on Observable subscription.
    return new Observable((observer: Observer<HttpEvent<any>>) => {
      ...
      // First up is the load event, which represents a response being fully available.
      const onLoad = () => {
        ...
        if (ok) {
          // A successful response is delivered on the event stream.
          observer.next(new HttpResponse({
            body,
            headers,
            status,
            statusText,
            url: url || undefined,
          }));
          // The full body has been received and delivered, no further events
          // are possible. This request is complete.
          observer.complete();   <---------------------------------
        }
```

> What if i want to implement catch function. Should i implement it before take or after take.

You can implement it after `take` since `take` will also transmit the error.

```
const stream = Observable.create((observer) => {
  observer.error(new Error());
}).take(1).catch(() => {
  return Observable.of(`An error occurred`);
}).subscribe((v) => {
  console.log(v);  // An error occurred
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is there any documentation on there is no need to call unsubscribe explicitly even without `take(1)` for angular `HttpClient` service to back up your statement?

Comment: For documentation, take (pardon the pun) a look at the [*Observable Contract*](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html). It's definitive. `take` completes the observable and completion sees any subscribers automatically unsubscribed.

Comment: @stackdisplay, updated the answer. The best documentation is the sources :). Check out angularindepth.com publication where all articles are published with that motto in mind

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com. Hi i have seen a lot of tutorial which suggest `async` pipe for auto unsubscribe with angular http request as example. However, based on your clarification, i think `async` pipe can be ignored for cleaner code. Or is there any benefit of still using `async` pipe?

Comment: @stackdisplay, can you please create another question? it will be beneficial for the community and others will be able to see and contribute to the answer

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com I have create the new question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46368846/benefits-of-async-pipe-with-angular-http-request