# Will overwriting my observable variable kill current subscribers?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I want to be able to cache an http call, but also force the cache to refresh. My service looks like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  private currentUser$: Observable<User>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCurrentUser(force = false): Observable<User> {
    if (!this.currentUser$ || force) {
      this.currentUser$ = this.http.get<User>(`${environment.API_URL}/profiles/me`)
        .pipe(
          shareReplay(CACHE_SIZE)
        );
    }
    return this.currentUser$;
  }
}
```

If I call `getCurrentUser(true)`, the `currentUser$` variable gets overwritten. I'm afraid this will wipe out any existing subscribers. Is this true? How can I preserve them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about `this.currentUser$` as pointing to an object on the heap. 
Your method returns a copy of the reference to `this.currentUser$`. So all subscribed observers will continue to listen to them (until all of them unsubscribe and the Observable gets garbage collected).

If you call the method with "force", the `this.currentUser$` will just point to another `Observable<User>` somewhere else on the heap.

Comment: So are you saying that I'd have two Observables in memory? One pointed to by the variable and one having no variable? Are you also saying that since the first Observable still has subscribers, it does not get garbage collected? Sounds like a memory leak.

Comment: Also, would the first Observable's subscribers no longer receive updates since there's no variable to push new values to?

Comment: Those are correct conclusions :). Of course, if you pass that Observable around, some other object can push new values. But I suppose that's not the case. Also, you have to be careful with memory leaks. Always unsubscribe from your Observables. There are many questions/answers floating around about this.

Comment: I'll accept your answer since it does answer my question, but could you take a look at [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52526737/64279) and let me know if you see any issues with it?

Comment: I don't have enough credits to comment on your code below :). But look at rxjs .take(1) to automatically unsubscribe after you received something.

Comment: Also, split up this methods in two separate methods. A) The action: One fetching users and put them in the Subject and B) for the 'observers': a method returning a member variable like `userObs$ = currentUser$.asObservable()`.

Comment: Thanks. I split the methods. I also removed the unsubscribe logic for the http call. Apparently `HttpClient` [does it for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46357047/64279)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post what I did here in case it helps anyone else. I return a single instance of `BehaviorSubject` instead and just push new values to it whenever I need to "force" getting the current user. I also added a flag `fetchingCurrentUser` so that I don't make multiple calls while I'm waiting for the first call to the API to complete.

Please let me know if anyone sees any issues with this or has any ideas on how to make it *cleaner*. Thanks.

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  private currentUser$: BehaviorSubject<User>;
  private fetchingCurrentUser: boolean;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.currentUser$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  }

  getCurrentUser(force = false): Observable<User> {
    if (this.currentUser$.value == null || force) {
      this.refreshCurrentUser();
    }
    return this.currentUser$.asObservable();
  }

  refreshCurrentUser() {
    if (!this.fetchingCurrentUser) {
      this.fetchingCurrentUser = true;
      this.http.get<User>(`${environment.API_URL}/profiles/me`)
        .subscribe(x => {
          this.currentUser$.next(x);
          this.fetchingCurrentUser = false;
        });
    }
  }
```