# How can I update an Observable without losing active subscribers?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm currently experiencing a bit of trouble trying to update a cached value using `publishReplay` and `refCount`.

First off, the method in question

```
getCurrentUser(): Observable<User> {
    if (!this.jwtService.getToken() || this.jwtService.getAnonymousToken()) { return of(null); }
    if (!this.currentUser$) {
      console.warn('user.service.getcurrentuser -> load and CACHE it once');
      this.currentUser$ = this.userService.loadCurrentUser().pipe(
        // https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/fastest-way-to-cache-for-lazy-developers-angular-with-rxjs-444a198ed6a6
        publishReplay(1),
        refCount()
      );
    }
    console.log('user.service.getcurrentuser -> get from CACHE');
    return this.currentUser$;
 }
```

`this.currentUser$` is an Observable of type `User`.

The method itself works as intended, the first call of the method loads the current user from the server. Subsequent calls then get the cached entry.
What I'm trying to do now, however, is to remove the cached value and reload the user from the server (ie. something was edited on the frontend and the user data requires reloading).

That I achieved by doing

```
removeCachedUser(): void {
  this.currentUser$ = null;
}
```

By doing this the `if` condition in the `getCurrentUser` method is triggered and the user is reloaded from the server. So far, so good.

The problem I'm facing is that methods that subscribed to `getCurrentUser` before the reset of the cache aren't receiving any updates, ie

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.currentUser$ = this.authService.getCurrentUser();
}
```

And my suspicion is that it's because of my overwriting the `this.currentUser$` Observable.

```
this.currentUser$ = this.userService.loadCurrentUser()
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52526275/12221382) more or less confirms my theory I suppose.

Am I right? And if so, what's the proper way to handle this issue? Unfortunately, I don't have a reactive backend so I have to trigger the reloads manually. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create an Observable that can emit multiple times to be able to send new values to active subscribers. In your current setup `this.currentUser$` completes when `this.userService.loadCurrentUser()` completes. I suspect `loadCurrentUser` is a http request that emits once and completes. So `this.currentUser$` can't emit multiple times.

To create an Observable that can emit multiple times use a `Subject` as the source and map to your http request. To get the user on the first subscribe to `currentUser$` before `reloadUser()` is called this `Subject` should be a `BehaviorSubject`.

```ts
private _reloadUser = new BehaviorSubject<void>(0 as void);

currentUser$ = this._reloadUser.pipe(
  switchMap(() => {
    if (!this.jwtService.getToken() || this.jwtService.getAnonymousToken()) { 
      return of(null); 
    }
    console.warn('user.service.getcurrentuser -> load and CACHE it');
    return this.userService.loadCurrentUser();
  }),
  shareReplay(1),
  tap(user => console.log('user from CACHE:', user))
) 

reloadUser() {
  this._reloadUser.next();
}
```

With `switchMap` a call to `reloadUser()` will cancel any ongoing load request and send a new load request. You could also use `exhaustMap` instead of `switchMap` if a call to `reloadUser()` shouldn't reload the user if the user is currently being loaded.

`shareReplay(1)` is be better suited than `publishReplay(1), refCount()` in this case because it doesn't have the `refCount` feature by default. With `publishReplay(1), refCount()` a new subscriber to `currentUser$` would trigger a load request if there aren't any subscribers present. `shareReplay(1)` will instead return the current user from the 'cache' in this case.

Comment: Tiny bit: switchMap seems more appropriate than exhaustMap here, at least if the current user can change to a different user, because exhaustMap might "miss" that if it happens too quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the line `this.currentUser$ = this.userService.loadCurrentUser()` is overwriting the property

### Solution

Make a `currentUser$` a `Subject` like below

```js
currentUserSubject$ = new BehaviourSubject<User | null>(null);
currentUser$ = this.currentUserSubject$.asObservable();
```

Now we refactor your code to

```js
getCurrentUser(): Observable<User> {
  if (!this.jwtService.getToken() || this.jwtService.getAnonymousToken()) { 
    return of(null); 
  }
    if (!this.currentUser$.value) {
      console.warn('user.service.getcurrentuser -> load and CACHE it once');
      return this.userService.loadCurrentUser().pipe(
        tap(user => this.currentUserSubject$.next(user)),
        // https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/fastest-way-to-cache-for-lazy-developers-angular-with-rxjs-444a198ed6a6
        publishReplay(1),
        refCount()
      );
    }
    console.log('user.service.getcurrentuser -> get from CACHE');
    return this.currentUser$;
 }
```

The clear cache function can be changed to

```
removeCachedUser(): void {
  this.currentUserSubject$.next(null);
}
```

Note the line `tap(user => this.currentUserSubject$.next(user)),` we tap into the observable stream and set the value of our subject using by calling the `next()` function on the `Subject` passing in the user

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`shareReplay`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47926240/when-should-i-use-publishreplay-vs-sharereplay/47926453#:%7E:text=publishReplay%20allows%20you%20to%20controls,to%20worry%20about%20unsubscribing%20etc.)
with combination of `takeUntil` to remove cache.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47926240/when-should-i-use-publishreplay-vs-sharereplay/47926453#:~:text=publishReplay%20allows%20you%20to%20controls,to%20worry%20about%20unsubscribing%20etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47926240/when-should-i-use-publishreplay-vs-sharereplay/47926453#:%7E:text=publishReplay%20allows%20you%20to%20controls,to%20worry%20about%20unsubscribing%20etc).

```
private _destroyCache$ = new Subject<void>();

getCurrentUser(): Observable<User> {
    if (!this.jwtService.getToken() || this.jwtService.getAnonymousToken()) { return of(null); }
    if (!this.currentUser$) {
        console.warn('user.service.getcurrentuser -> load and CACHE it once');
        this.currentUser$ = this.userService.loadCurrentUser().pipe(
            takeUntil(this._destroyCache$),
            shareReplay(1),
        );
    }
    console.log('user.service.getcurrentuser -> get from CACHE');
    return this.currentUser$;
}

removeCachedUser(): void {
    this.currentUser$ = null;
    this._destroyCache$.next();
    this._destroyCache$.compleate();
    this._destroyCache$ = new Subject<void>();
}
```

And on the component you can have something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    loadData();
}

loadData() {
    this.currentUser$ = this.authService.getCurrentUser();
}

refreshData() {
    this.authService.removeCachedUser();
    loadData();
}
```